# Generating PDF in 11 * 17 (Landscape) with XSLT

Tags: pdf, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have this requirement wherein I need to create a PDS in 11 * 17 size and in landscape format with XSLT. I am able to create PDF in A4 page size using XSl FO.

My XSLT is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family = "Helvetica" font-size = "10px">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.75cm" margin-right="0.75cm" margin-top="0.5cm" master-name="first" page-height="27.9cm" page-width="21.6cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-bottom = "0.5cm" margin-top = "0.25cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent = "0cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent = "0.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <xsl:for-each select="Rowsets">
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="first">
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                        <fo:block font-size="8pt" line-height="6pt" text-align-last="justify">
                            Shift Report
                            <fo:inline id="Date">
                                Date [currentDate]
                            </fo:inline>
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern = "space"/>
                            Page
                            <fo:page-number/>
                        </fo:block>                 
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <xsl:for-each select="Rowset">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="Columns/Column[1]/@Description = 'Break'">
                                    <fo:block page-break-before="always" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <fo:table border-color="black" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                                        <xsl:variable name="columns">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="count(Columns/Column)" />
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()&lt;2">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="62pt" />
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()&gt;1 and position()&lt;4">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="40pt" />
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()&gt;4 and position()&lt;6">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="40pt" />
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()&gt;8">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="60pt" />
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                    <fo:table-column />
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                        <fo:table-body font-size="10pt">
                                            <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                <fo:table-cell background-color="#000000" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt" number-columns-spanned="{$columns}">
                                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="center" color="#FFFFFF">
                                                        Shift Report
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                            </fo:table-row>
                                                <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                                        <fo:table-cell background-color="#CCCCCC" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="left">
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="translate(@Name,'_',' ')" />
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </fo:table-row>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                                                <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                                                        <fo:table-cell background-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                            <fo:block font-weight="normal" text-align="left">
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </fo:table-row>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </fo:table-body>
                                    </fo:table>
                                    <fo:block text-indent="2pc" space-after="7pt" space-before.minimum="6pt" space-before.optimum="8pt" space-before.maximum="10pt">
                                    </fo:block>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure where does  have to make change in order to accomodate 11 * 17 size and landscape orientation.

Also, one of the column(header) name is "QualityPercent". I would like to change it to "Quality%"

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Change `page-height="27.9cm" page-width="21.6cm"` to `page-height="11in" page-width="17in"`.

---

There's also the `size` shorthand (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#size).  If it's supported, you can use `size="17in 11in"`.  Some formatters (including AH Formatter: https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.size) recognise some set of keywords for the paper size, such that you can also use `size="Ledger"`.

---

Edited:

Change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@Name,'_',' ')" />
```

to

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(@Name, 'Percent')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Name, 'Percent')" />
    <xsl:text>%</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(@Name,'_',' ')" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

If you were using XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0), you could use `replace()` to more easily and accurately replace `Percent` with `%` in any `@Name` value.

Comment: What about makin git landscape? Also, how can I refer QUalityPercent column in XSLT to change it to Quality%?

Comment: It's landscape when the width is greater than the height, as above.  Sorry, I misunderstood about QualityPercent: I thought it was part of your text.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Great. I will try that and let you know. One last question : I have a column called ActualTarget. I do not want to include that column and its values in the PDF tale. How can I avoid the column "ActualTarget"?

Comment: Sorry, but that probably needs a question of its own, since it would help to also see your XML along with your current XSLT and to get an indication of whether table cells can ever span multiple columns.